# Create XmlRpcUrl Interface at runtime

Tags: url, configuration, interface, dynamic, xml-rpc

Currently I'm creating my XML-RPC using (xml-rpc.net) interfaces statically with the following statement:

```
[XmlRpcUrl("http://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php")]
public interface ICSBlog : IMetaWeblog
{
}
```

However, I'd like to be able to specify the URL for the service at runtime, so I can dynamically switch to different services as needed.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The URL can be set at runtime, for example:

```
ISumAndDiff proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<ISumAndDiff>();
proxy.Url = "http://www.cookcomputing.com/SumAndDiff.rem";   
SumAndDiffValue ret = proxy.SumAndDifference(2, 3);
```

This assumes the proxy interface derives from IXmlRpcProxy. If not, you have have to cast to IXmlRpcProxy to set the Url property.