# Set interface decoration dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, interface

I'm currently creating a C# library for a danish newsletter provider which uses xml-rpc for their API. For the library I'm using xml-rpc.net to communicate with their API.

I want to make this library generic, so that it can be used in other projects aswell. The interface that is required by xml-rpc.net needs to be decorated by the URL of the API, like this:

```
[XmlRpcUrl("https://myclienturl/xmlrpc/")]
public interface MyInterface: IXmlRpcProxy
```

My question is: is there any way to use a dynamic string in this decoration rather than a hardcoded one? :-)

**EDIT**
D'oh, it seems that I wasn't the only one wondering. Solution is found here: [Create XmlRpcUrl Interface at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111842/create-xmlrpcurl-interface-at-runtime?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have dynamic attributes.

Attributes are compiled into your final assembly, arguments and all.

Your only chance is that the code that reads those attributes can react to something dynamic, other than the attributes, or be overridden in some way.

Comment: ouch, I guess I saw that one coming ;-) Thanks a lot Lasse! Back to the drawingboard then.